# How can I have overflow height setting with the %?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a code over here and trying to overflow the SearchLocationCards. It works with the 'px' and 'vh' values, however, when I try to use '%' value, it doesn't work at all. How can I size the scrollable box with % height values?

```
<div className={{ maxHeight: '100%' }}>
  <SearchDrawer />
  <div style={{ overflow: 'auto', height: '85vh' }}>
    <SearchedLocationCards
      searchedLocations={props.searchedLocation.results}
    />
  </div>
  <Paginated
    align='center'
    justify='center'
    direction='column'
    totalPage={100}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the parent of `div` has some height and not `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the div maxHeight to '100%' which is going to grow to the same height as the child. Try setting the div height to '100%' or some other fixed value and then you will be able to use % for height in the child div.

If % does not work in a child component it is always because the parent is not as big as you think it is.

You could try:

```
<div className={{ height: '100%' }}>
  // Child tags
</div>
```

or:

```
<div className={{ height: '100vh' }}>
  // Child tags
</div>
```

but without knowing the height of the parent component to this one, there is no guarantee this will work. The point is that you need to trace up the tree until you find which tag is limiting the size.

Comment: I realized I had to define 100% to all my div above :/ CSS is killing me haha.